# Django button not submit when i have onclick

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

My form has a submit button that should submit the form then open a popup with onclick event.
With the onclick event enabled the form will not submit, however if it's disabled the form is submitted correctly.

```
<div class="container-login-form-btn">
  <input onclick="openPopup(event)" class="login-form-btn" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>
  <div class="popup" id="popup">
      <h1 type="submit">OTP Verification</h1>
      <p>Code has been send</p>
      <div class="otp-card-inputs">
          {{ otp }}
      </div>
      <p>Didn't get the otp <a href="#">Resend</a> </p>
      <input class= "verify-otp-btn" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </div>
```

```
function openPopup(event){
popup.classList.add("open-popup");
event.preventDefault();
}
```

```
.popup {
  width: 900px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 30px 30px;
  color: #333;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.4s, top 0.4s;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 40px -20px black;
}

.open-popup {
  visibility: visible;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

I'm trying to show the popup and to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because the `click event` on the input element is overriding the `submit event`.

If you want to submit the form on click, use it like this-

Remove submit type from the input-

```
<input onclick="openPopup(event)" class="login-form-btn" value="Submit"/>
```

Submit the form when calling the function to open the popup but make sure your form has an id.

```
function openPopup(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //form submission
  document.getElementById("form_id").submit(); 
  // open popup
  popup.classList.add("open-popup");
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, but now, the popup close instantly because the page is refreshed how i can make for keep my popup open ?

Comment: Try adding this on your form, `<form onsubmit="return false"></form>` or move `event.preventDefault();` after form submit.

Comment: It don't work, i have tried this two solution and its same.